# What are the requirements and how to submit a SU blog?

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog

What the requirements for submitting a [Super User Community Blog](http://blog.superuser.com) post? After the post has been created, how is it submitted?

Comment: I may have used the wrong tag. Is *support* a better tag?

Comment: Are you talking about a blog post here?

Comment: Yay! More potential bloggers! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the information on the [How to Contribute to the Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/contribute/) page:

> 1. Read the [About](http://blog.superuser.com/about/) page
> 2. Write a post on something you find interesting or think the
>      community would enjoy – use your creativity, just about anything
>      interesting and related to computers is probably fine
> 3. Submit your post to an editor. We have several categories, as
>      explained on the about page, explained below in more detail. If your
>      post doesn’t quite fit, no worries - email your post to Ivo Flipse or
>      Kronos, and they can get you headed in the right direction.
> 4. A Super User Blog editor will contact you once they receive your
>      post, and let you know if they have any suggestions.
> 5. If you would like to contribute frequently, we can create an
>      account for you on the blog so that you won’t have to submit posts by
>      email. Your posts will still be approved by an editor before being
>      posted.
> 6. Once you’ve submitted at least three high quality posts, you are
>      eligible to receive a free Super User T-shirt!

We also have [a meta post set up](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3275/submit-your-blog-post-for-the-super-user-contest-here) for new bloggers to submit posts to be considered in the Super User Contest.

There are no real "requirements" per se - just write about something you think is interesting and that has something to do with computers, technology or Super User. Blog posts don't have the same strict rules for what is on topic like the main site does, so be creative!

So, if you'd like to write a post for us, you can either put it in that meta post, or you can email it to [me](https://superuser.com/users/20088/nhinkle) or [Kronos](https://superuser.com/users/47225/kronos) (Ivo Flipse can't receive email right now, so don't send your post to him). Our contact info is listed on our Super User profiles. I look forward to seeing what you have to contribute to the blog! If you have any more questions, please leave a comment or come talk to us in the [SU Blog Editors chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/356/super-user-blog-editor-room).

Once you have an account set up on the blog, you won't need to email us for every new post. You'll be able to mark a post as "pending review", and a blog editor will publish it for you wherever it fits in our schedule.