# Who gets to post to the blog?

Tags: support, superuser-blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the requirements and how to submit a SU blog?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3323/what-are-the-requirements-and-how-to-submit-a-su-blog)

What is required for a person to be permitted to post to the blog?

- Do they have to be a Moderator?
- Do they have to be a "Valued Associate"?
- Do they have to have a certain amount of reputation?

Comment: [The Super User blog is looking for writers!](http://meta.superuser.com/q/2278)

Comment: No, no, and [not more than 48](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/28/5-ways-of-finding-the-right-power-supply/).

Comment: Here are a few links that will help:  [What are the requirements and how to submit a SU blog?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3323/what-are-the-requirements-and-how-to-submit-a-su-blog) [Contribute to the blog](http://blog.superuser.com/contribute/)

Comment: Voting to close this, so nobody has to come up with an answer ;-) Just check the linked topics. Basically everybody who wants to contribute can submit a blog post. There are also other editors available for suggestions and proofreading.

Comment: Oh and since you were asking (and since we're having trouble recruiting writers), was it hard for you to find this information? Is there any way we could make it more transparent? We'd really like to get more attention to the blog again.

Comment: @slhck, Yes. (disclaimer: I have never used a blog system, only StackExchange Q&A site and forums, etc.) My first impression was that this is something done by the staff, and other highly privileged users (Moderators, Valued Associates) of StackExchange, as there was no indication otherwise. I found out just recently [some indication that SuperUser's Blog was community driven](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110998). I could not find **Contribute**, **How To Post**, **Write An Article**, or anything like that on the top bottom or side. I **couldn't even find FAQ**. **:)**

Comment: @slhck, Well it turns out it was under the categories. My recommendation is to place it at the top and bottom as well. And prominently. Like the Ask A Question button. Does not matter that it instructs us to send email.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! We'll try to do better then! :)

Comment: @GeorgeBailey: Check out the upcoming blog post in about three hours. We've also put this in the back-end and will try to make it somewhat more easy accessible. Under the categories is indeed not the best place to put it...