# So you've submitted your blog post... Now what?

Tags: support, superuser-blog, windows-8-challenge

Congratulations to those of you that [submitted your blog posts](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5722/the-windows-8-challenge-has-ended)!  If you had a positive overall score on your post you've been entered into the Windows 8 Contest Blog Tile drawing.

But you may be asking yourself, what's the next step?  Well, now we're going to have you port over your blog entry into the blog itself.  Below is a little introduction to the site and suggestions on how to do this.

## Blog.SuperUser.com/wp-admin

The above url is the main portal into the site.  From there you can add posts, view comments and all sorts of fun stuff.  Thanks to @RebeccaChernoff the blog now seemlessly integrates with your Stackexchange Account!  This means that once you log into a Stack Exchange site you can log into any blog.  However your default role in the blog is "Subscriber" which means you can only add comments to posts.  We'll have to upgrade you to a "Contributor".

As a Contributor you'll be able to upload your blog posts to the site. To request Contributor status, send either me (@Kronos) or @Nhinkle a ping over at [Super User Blog Editors Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/356/super-user-blog-editor-room) room requesting to be a Contributor.  We'll upgrade your account and you'll be on your merry way.

## Uploading the post

Using the online editor is pretty straight forward.  Navigate to `Posts` --> `Add New` and you'll be presented to the online editor.  Be sure to save your work:

[image]

Once you've finished editing your post and it's to your satisfaction ping either @Nhinkle or I and we'll edit and approve. Also, keep your blog entry status updated on the Trello board for the Blog (We'll add you to the board when you sign up to be a contributor).

## When will my post be live for the World to see?

Since the blog is pretty small, we won't be publishing these posts everyday.  We'll be publishing them about a week apart.  That means that potentially your post could be posted 10-12 weeks from now.  I will consider posts first come first serve highest quality.  Meaning that if your post isn't uploaded to the blog, and you haven't indicated that it's ready, I won't publish it.

I will also consider higher quality posts over lower one.  This means that you really need to make these shine if you want me to publish them first ;)  If you have questions on this, feel free to ask us over at the chat room.  We will gladly help you as we want all of you to succeed.

## This isn't limited to just contest entrants

Anyone can follow these steps and become blog contributors.  If you contribute on a regular basis you'll be given more responsibilities (i.e. editing other peoples content, publishing directly to the site, etc,.).  So if you want to join the blogging team feel free to do so.

Comment: Is this true for every blog? (not just superuser)

Comment: @Earlz as far as what?  I'm not sure how other SE blogs are setup as far as who is in control, but I do know that they are all administrated using the same tools, so I imagine that the process is the same for the other ones.

Comment: Well, I'd love to try my hand at getting a post onto stackoverflow's blog... More of a programmer than a superuser :) Any ideas who I'd ping to get contributer status over there?

Comment: @KronoS my blog had a score of 0. Am I in or not in? (It does say I've completed the blog tile on my userpage.)

Comment: Please learn the difference between *everyday* (which means "humdrum, ordinary") and *every day* (which means, um, every day). They're even pronounced differently, for heaven's sake.